# Use two models in ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a ListView for every budget category in my list of transactions. For each of these views, I'd like to show the actual budget for this category. For instance, my Bill budget has sub budgets for rent, insurance, phone, etc which is stored in a separate model from the transactions. The current ListView just sends the transactions filtered by budget type:

```
class BillListView(ListView):
    model = Transaction
    template_name = 'budget/base_transactions.html'
    context_object_name = 'transactions'
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Transaction.objects.filter(budget_type__exact='bill')
```

Is there a way to send the sub budget data from my budget database as well so I can display it at the top of the template?

My models:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    budget_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description + ' ' + str(self.amount)

class Budget(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
```

Comment: Can you post your models too?

Comment: Don't your models `Transaction` and `Budget` have any relation?

Comment: They're related with the category attribute. How do I take advantage of that in this scenario?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your models as there are no foreign keys or relational fields defined in your models.

Comment: The Transaction model pulls all transactions from my account. The Budget model stores the subcategory budgets. Do I need foreign keys here to make what I'm trying to do work?

Comment: Can you try to explain the relation between the models, if there exists any? Also can you properly describe how you intend to display the data in the template?

Comment: Transactions contains all banking transactions from my bank account. Each transaction is categorized as either a bill, debt, subscription, expense, etc. and contains the transaction, date and amount. Budget contains sub budget info. Each row contains which budget it belongs to, the sub budget name, and the amount. For instance 'bill' 'rent' 1000 or 'bill' 'phone' 100. You can have an unlimited number of sub budgets per budget. I was planning on loading the sub budget for each page at the top, so the Bill ListView will display how much I've budgeted for rent, phone bill, etc.

Comment: As per my understanding, a transaction object can contain sub-categories stored in the budget model. Is it correct?

Comment: Well no, as you can see from the model declaration, they aren't programmatically connected in any way. Only theoretically. But yes, the category names in Budget are based on the category names in Transaction

Comment: So in the template, you need to show the sub categories and its amount for each transaction?

Comment: I need to show the transactions for that category and the budget for that category

Comment: Is `bill` a category for both transaction and budget objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass data of another model through the `ListView`, you might be looking for overriding the `get_context_data` method of `ListView`. Then you can be able to pass required data along with our model objects.

For example:

In your context, where you want to show data about the budget objects, you can change your `BillListView` view as:

```
class BillListView(ListView):
    model = Transaction
    template_name = 'budget/base_transactions.html'
    context_object_name = 'transactions'
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Transaction.objects.filter(budget_type__exact='bill')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BillListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['budgets'] = Budget.objects.filter(category__exact='bill') //filter as per required
        return context
```

Then you can access the `budget` objects in the template by looping through `budgets` as:

```
{% for budget in budgets %}
    {{ budget.amount }}
    {{ budget.sub_category }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I needed, thank you. I'm sure my code isn't structured perfectly which is probably why it was hard for me to explain it. But that works how I need it to